# Cross site webservice ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-domain

I have a working webservice on site A, I have no problem consuming this service from within site A, now I am trying to consume the same service from site B with no success...

Code follows -

```
$(function () {
            $.getJSON("http://siteA.com/Services/myasmx.asmx/dummy",
                {
                    sID: "tempID"
                },
            function (data) {
                //success call
.
.
                return false;
                  });
              });
        });
```

Any idea how can I consume site A webservice from site B ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Cross-site HTTP Requests are not allowed by modern browsers as a security measure. The correct way to work around this is to use JSONP callback in the URL.

```
$.getJSON("http://siteA.com/Services/myasmx.asmx/dummy?jsoncallback=?",
    function(data){
      // do something here
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use $.ajax with dataType: "jsonp" - this will automatically register your callback function for you and avoid the cross domain issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is because cross-domain policy.

If you can had some headers in the response of the webservice, you can easily bypass that.

see : http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/